# Magento 2 Translation Extension by Magefan error

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

After deploy Magento 2 Translation Extension by Magefan i got following error

```
{"0":"Warning: class_implements(): Class TranslationGridDataProvider does not exist and could not be loaded in \/home\/419982.cloudwaysapps.com\/vftydjkdjd\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Code\/Reader\/ClassReader.php on line 71","1":"<pre>#1 class_implements('TranslationGridD...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Code\/Reader\/ClassReader.php:71]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getParents('TranslationGridD...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponent\/Argument\/Interpreter\/ConfigurableObject.php:118]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponent\\Argument\\Interpreter\\ConfigurableObject->getParents('TranslationGridD...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponent\/Argument\/Interpreter\/ConfigurableObject.php:96]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponent\\Argument\\Interpreter\\ConfigurableObject->evaluate(array('name' => 'dataProvider', 'argument' => array('class' => array('name' => 'class', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'TranslationGridD...'), 'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'translation_tran...'), 'primaryFieldName' => array('name' => 'primaryFieldName', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'key_id'), 'requestFieldName' => array('name' => 'requestFieldName', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'id'), 'data' => array('name' => 'data', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('config' => array('name' => 'config', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('component' => array('name' => 'component', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'Magento_Ui\/js\/gr...'), 'update_url' => array('name' => 'update_url', 'xsi:type' => 'url', 'path' => 'mui\/index\/render'), 'storageConfig' => array('name' => 'storageConfig', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('indexField' => array('name' => 'indexField', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'key_id')))))))))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Data\/Argument\/InterpreterInterface\/Proxy.php:95]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Argument\\InterpreterInterface\\Proxy->evaluate(array('name' => 'dataProvider', 'argument' => array('class' => array('name' => 'class', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'TranslationGridD...'), 'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'translation_tran...'), 'primaryFieldName' => array('name' => 'primaryFieldName', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'key_id'), 'requestFieldName' => array('name' => 'requestFieldName', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'id'), 'data' => array('name' => 'data', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('config' => array('name' => 'config', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('component' => array('name' => 'component', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'Magento_Ui\/js\/gr...'), 'update_url' => array('name' => 'update_url', 'xsi:type' => 'url', 'path' => 'mui\/index\/render'), 'storageConfig' => array('name' => 'storageConfig', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('indexField' => array('name' => 'indexField', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'key_id')))))))))) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Argument\/Interpreter\/Composite.php:61]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Argument\\Interpreter\\Composite->evaluate(array('name' => 'dataProvider', 'argument' => array('class' => array('name' => 'class', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'TranslationGridD...'), 'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'translation_tran...'), 'primaryFieldName' => array('name' => 'primaryFieldName', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'key_id'), 'requestFieldName' => array('name' => 'requestFieldName', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'id'), 'data' => array('name' => 'data', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('config' => array('name' => 'config', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('component' => array('name' => 'component', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'Magento_Ui\/js\/gr...'), 'update_url' => array('name' => 'update_url', 'xsi:type' => 'url', 'path' => 'mui\/index\/render'), 'storageConfig' => array('name' => 'storageConfig', 'xsi:type' => 'array', 'item' => array('indexField' => array('name' => 'indexField', 'xsi:type' => 'string', 'value' => 'key_id')))))))))) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Config\/Data.php:164]\n#7 Magento\\Ui\\Config\\Data-
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that when installing [Magento 2 Translation Extension](https://magefan.com/magento-2-translation-extension) you followed the [installation instructions](https://magefan.com/magento-2-translation-extension/installation), especially the step

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```